# Rails - Using Paperclip with no model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

is it possible to use Paperclip without a model? I just need the ability for an admin user to upload a pdf to a specific dir and that pdf can be overwritten when a more current pdf is uploaded.

I'm on rails 2.3.5.

Thanks.

Comment: For a simple requirement as yours, I would rather do it myself instead of using a plugin that is really meant for something more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the problem with introducting a PDF model to use? It's easy enough.

If you don't want that model, then don't use paperclip and save the attachments yourself, they come in as instances of `TempFile`.

Comment: I was already using polymorphic paperclip for some more complex asynchronous multi image uploads and though that might be unnecessary for the simple pdf upload. But I ended up creating a model for the pdfs as well to use the progress indicator as some of the pdfs can be quite large.